# Search by more than one tag in Rawg.io

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am currently developing an application that matches the user with a list of games based in their preferences (I'm running a personality test that returns a string of keywords). My API call looks like this:

```
 let API_URL = `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=XXXXX`;
    fetch(
          `${
            API_URL + `&tags=action,cooperative,farm&page_size=20&page=1`
          }`
        )
```

I would be expecting the results to include the tags action, cooperative and farm; but, instead, I get a list of results that include just one of them. Myself and teachers/relatives have been investigating through the API docs to see if there is a way to force the query parameters to be concatenated, but no luck so far.

Does anyone have a clue about if this is possible? I'm going to get in touch with Rawg.io's team as well and post if I get an answer from them.

P.S. Any other gaming database with this possibility would also be happily appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to think about "tags" and "genres" filters. For example "horror" : that's not a "genre" but a "tag". "Survival-horror" is the same.

I use this API too and i can filter games using 2 tags : "&tags=horror,survival-horror"  and it's work.
To answer your question, i'm not sure that "action" is a tag..it should probably be a "genre".
It's the only way i can understand your issue.

PS : i just tried it on my API and this works

```
"&genres=action&tags=cooperative,farm"
```